# Is it correct to say "She hid quite a figure behind the wardrobe"?

Tags: grammar, expressions, idioms

I'm writing a story for my English class. Does the following sentence effectively mean that she had a good figure behind her dress?

> She hid quite a figure behind the Wardrobe.

Does it apply to both male and female?

Comment: Not unless she was wearing a wardrobe for a dress :) Hiding one's figure behind a wardrobe does not really make sense.

Comment: I'm sure clothes designers would weep! They think good dresses (and good clothes in general) are supposed to accentuate and *show off* a good figure, not *hide* it.

Comment: @MarvMills Unless her name is  Lucy Pevensie, then it's a whole world she hid behind her wardrobe.

Comment: @P.Obertelli 'behind' or '*within*'? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Those who have good figures could show off by wearing good skin-tight dresses; but, if one has a bad figure, one may hide one's figure by wearing a loose dress.

Comment: This is a style question. "She hid quite a figure behind her wardrobe" might work with some context, assuming 'hiding' and 'wardrobe' are interpreted a little metaphorically and the previous text leads one to think that. Are you trying to say that she has a good figure, and that her _modest_ clothes hide that? Then maybe 'modest wardrobe'. People tend not to use 'figure' for males. By the way, out of context it sounds like this woman is physically hiding behind a large piece of furniture.

Comment: Also, rereading it, I interpret it as 'This girl was kind of large and so she needed something as big as a wardrobe to hide behind'. Of course again context would disambiguate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Wardrobe* means both the set of clothing that a person owns and a particular piece of furniture to put clothing in. When you say "behind the wardrobe", I picture the furniture because it implies you mean a physical place.

> She hid quite a figure with her wardrobe.

Would be a clearer way to phrase it, although it's still a little confusing. Adding the possessives makes it feel more like you are talking about her person, and *with* tells us that her wardrobe is a manner of hiding, so I'm more likely to think you are talking about clothes since it would be difficult to use furniture for that purpose, although really it could mean that she is hiding amongst the fur coats inside her wardrobe. Still, this would only really apply if all of her clothes we designed to hide her physical form. If you are describing her entrance into a scene rather than generally describing what kind of person she is, I would be more specific about what she was wearing.

> She hid quite a figure with her loose shift.

Or something.

You could use this for a man, but we don't talk about a man as having a *figure*. You would probably use the term *physique* instead.

> He hid his brawny physique with frumpy wardrobe choices.

Now that you've clarified that you want to say she had a nice figure no matter what she wore, I'm going to suggest that you change the sentence entirely. *Hiding* suggests intent, so you want to change that to something more neutral:

> She had quite a figure despite her wardrobe.

Would convey precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I really wanted to say readers that she had a really attractive figure despite her dress. It doesn't matter how bad or good her dress is, Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @Klags That's quite a crass and possibly lascivious thing to put in a story. Perhaps it is something you should allude to in a more subtle way?

Comment: @Klags ...such as 'Her dress was often incapable of fully concealing the allure of her glorious figure...'

Comment: Hi Klags - did you mean "beneath" or "behind" ?

Comment: Hi Marv, your comment *"that's quite a crass and possibly lascivious thing to put in a story"* seems incredibly extreme.  (And I'm a puritan.) Could it be you misread something?  The sentence, ***"She hid quite a figure behind her wardrobe."***, I would read to my 8 yr old, even though I'm a puritan.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the fact is **it does make sense**.  (With a couple minor repairs.)

A sophisticated reader would understand that by "wardrobe" you, uh, effectively mean "her clothing collection" (not the wooden piece of furniture which holds that clothing collection).

Note though that **you should definitely change "the" to "her"**.  It is much clearer then.

(I can see some obscure preamble situations where "the" or perhaps "that" (or "the other" or "the second" or "the new" etc) would work .... but as a general thought it should certainly be "her wardrobe" for clarity.)

Further, as Kit has nicely explained, you could go with "with her wardrobe" rather than "behind her wardrobe".

However, I do feel it makes complete sense, to any sophisticated reader, as

> She hid quite a figure behind her wardrobe.

Nice sentence.

Note - there's no capital "w".

Comment: I think ***your*** version makes sense, when the sentence ends with _behind her wardrobe_ (as opposed to the O.P.'s original, which read _behind the Wardrobe)._ Without those modifications, I'm afraid the sentence is "on the right track" at best.

Answer (score -1):

The word *wardrobe* refers to her clothing. An added qualifier would improve this sentence, e.g.

> She hid quite a figure behind her drab wardrobe.